# Debug COM object using .NET client

Tags: com, debugging

I have a legacy COM object written in C++ that I need to debug from a C# client.  I just need to step through the C++ code, not the C# code.  Is this possible?  How does one go about setting this up?

Answer (score 1):

When you have the source code for the COM server, load it in VS20xx and set your .NET application as program to start. Add breakpoints at the class creation function and to the methods at the COM server's interface.

When you run the program, VS might claim the program does not have debug information. Ignore that, your COM server has debug information.

Answer (score 1):

Start the client without the debugger, then attach the debugger selecting "Native code" in the debugger settings.